# Deploying .net Core web app to ubuntu linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, ubuntu, web-applications, coreclr

I had an app I was developing in asp.net 4.5 and I wanted to move it to asp.net core and run on linux server (ubuntu).

I've been having a number of challanges and unfortunately current documentation is not helpful.

so...

How should I package the app?

The tech docs suggest building with the following command

> dnu publish --runtime dnx-coreclr-linux-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1

However I tried this on my local machine and it didn't have option to deploy linux version. When I run on server it comes up with a number of problems (covered later). So should I do this on server or get working on local machine.

NB: I read in another stack overflow question that as long as its coreclr it doesn't matter whether its win or linux?

I imagine after this is answered more questions will emerge..I've had so many issues with Core I'm wondering whether anybody has actually manged to deploy on app to Linux environment!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

To provide further information current runtimes on local machine are...

Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                    Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                    -----
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x64          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x64          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x86          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr     x86          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes default
       1.0.0-rc1-update2 coreclr x86          C:\Users\Alex.dnx\runtimes

I want to compile it as coreclr linux....however when I run the dnu publish command above it says runtime doesn't exist even though I update coreclr from nuget?

Do I need to specify an OS (linux or windows) when I build it or will a single published app run on both if its coreclr?

This runs fine when imported into Azure but doesn't work when deployed to linux

Comment: You never actually said what errors you're getting. And yes, people can and have deployed their apps to Linux. If you're still learning ASP.NET, it's probably better to *not* use the bleeding edge stuff that's still in flux and lacking documentation.

Comment: hopefully extra information above provides further info. Ta

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's how to:

1. Install Visual Studio 2017 (with .NET Core)
2. Create your project, and get it to compile on Windows
3. Once it compiles and runs, make sure you can publish it from Visual Studio
4. Once you can publish it from Visual Studio, close Visual Studio and do the following

   open cmd.exe (Windows-Key + R)
   cd "directory of your .sln file"
   dotnet restore -r ubuntu.16.04-x64
   dotnet build -r ubuntu.16.04-x64
   dotnet publish -f netcoreapp1.1 -c Release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64
5. Your application should now be in folder bin/publish

A list of RIDs (-r) can be obtained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/rid-catalog.md).

If you want to develop on Linux, run

```
apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1
```

and the dotnet-utility should run on Linux.

Note that if you get

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2865,5):
> error MSB3554: Cannot write to the output file "C:\path\to\your\project\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\YOUR_APP.Properties.Resources.resources".
> Positive number required.
>
> Build FAILED.

when you run the build or publish command, just run the command again.